# How to convert map object to array in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I am getting Json in this format from server

```
Details:{1:"John",2:"Josh"}
```

I want to convert it into this FormArray format

```
Details:[{"Number": 1, "Name": John},{"Number": 2, "Name": Josh}]
```

How can I achieve it? I am using Angular 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const input = {1:"John",2:"Josh"};
const output = Object.keys(input).map((key) => {
  return {
    Number: key,
    Name: input[key]
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

You just need to use `Object.keys()` to get all the keys of your object in an array and just iterate over them and map them in a new array.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const input = { 1: "John", 2: "Josh" };
let Details = [];

for (let key of Object.keys(input)) {
  let detail = { "Number": key, "Name": input[key] };

  Details.push(detail);
}
```

I suggest if you have access to the server code you should modify it to return the data in the format you want, as this will slow down your application (frontend) when the server returns an object containing say 1000+ items.

Comment: I cannot change the server side code. But thanks for the reply.This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are missing one bit and that is the conversion of `Number` to well, a `number`:

```
const input = {1:"John",2:"Josh"};
const output = Object.keys(input).map((key) => {
  return {
    Number: parseInt(key, 10), // This bit
    Name: input[key]
  }
});
```